# Using easepick as a daterange picker solution for calendars within a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, datepicker, shadow-dom

I want to use easepick within a chrome extension so I can't reference an external style sheet. I tried setting css to a local copy of the file and it doesn't work, from searching it seems like it's a requirement per shadowdom. Any suggestions on how to avoid the external reference?

```
const picker = new easepick.create({
                element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
                css: "../css/easepick.css",
                plugins: ['RangePlugin'],
                RangePlugin: {
                  tooltipNumber(num) {
                    return num - 1;
                  },
                  locale: {
                    one: 'night',
                    other: 'nights',
                  },
                },
              });
```

Pointing to a local style sheet doesn't work like I show above.

Comment: I think you should use [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/web-accessible-resources).